# Planning to remove SSL: will that solve my slow loading time and will I still be able to have secure login/signup?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ssl, heroku

my site is a Rails app hosted on Heroku. I'm planning to remove SSL for the site (just going to comment out the config.force_ssl line).

I am planning to change things up and use SSL only for login/signup but will that fix my problem. I would have the login/signup on the regular home page (i.e. not SSL), but the action for the login/signup forms would be https://mysite.com/sessions as opposed to just /sessions.

I don't know much about SSL or web apps in general to be honest, so I am curious - will that ensure that my site's login/signup are secure, but at the same time take away the long SSL negotiation time I am suffering right now?

Thanks so much!
Ringo

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that SSL is causing a slow down in performance. Years ago when hardware was lesser powered it would have been a consideration but with the massive CPU power we have these days a SSL handshake is quick, you only have to look at gmail, facebook etc that all run permanently in SSL.

Your best bet would be to use NewRelic to look for any performance gains you could make through your code.

Comment: Thanks for your response! So when I check my performance with webpagetest.org, I find that SSL negotiation is taking ~800ms-1s. The rest of the time to first byte is my app ... and that takes ~200-300ms. Its not SSL generally that is causing a problem but rather the entire SSL negotiation process.

Comment: Hi, did commenting out the line work? I tried doing that but cannot seem to get rid of the ssl.